# Akka Streams (Scala): Filtering out exceptions

Tags: scala, akka-stream, flatmap

One of the steps in my akka streams pipeline is a transformation that throws an exception when it receives an invalid input.  I would like to discard these problematic inputs.  So, I came up with the following solution:

```
...
.map( input => Try( transformation( input ) ).toOption )
.filter( _.nonEmpty )
.map( _.get )
...
```

Which takes 3 steps for what is, in fact, just a flatMap.

Is there a more straightforward akka way of doing this?

Answer (score 3):

You can use Supervision Strategies. Taken from the doc:

```
val decider: Supervision.Decider = {
  case _: ArithmeticException => Supervision.Resume
  case _                      => Supervision.Stop
}

val flow = Flow[Int]
  .filter(100 / _ < 50)
  .map(elem => 100 / (5 - elem))
  .withAttributes(ActorAttributes.supervisionStrategy(decider))
```

You can configure the Decider for doing whatever you need. If you need to skip that element for all Exceptions use

```
 case _: Throwable => Supervision.Resume
```

Take a look to https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/stream-error.html

Comment: Note that not all stages will respect supervision strategies (partly because a strategy may not always make sense for a given stage).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to silently discard the exceptions as indicated in your sample code, here's a couple of ways to reduce the steps:

```
// A dummy transformation
def transformation(i: Int): Int = 100 / i

// #1: Use `collect`
Source(List(5, 2, 0, 1)).
  map(input => Try(transformation(input)).toOption).
  collect{ case x if x.nonEmpty => x.get }.
  runForeach(println)
  // Result: 20, 50, 100

// #2: Use `mapConcat`
Source(List(5, 2, 0, 1)).
  mapConcat(input => List(Try(transformation(input)).toOption).flatten).
  runForeach(println)
  // Result: 20, 50, 100
```

Note that there is no `flatMap` for Akka Source/Flow, although [`mapConcat`](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.6/stream/operators/Source-or-Flow/mapConcat.html) (and `flatMapConcat`) does function in a somewhat similar fashion.